# How do you replace backslash double quote in a string?

Tags: javascript

How do replace backslash double quote (e.g. \") in a string?

The code below does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var myVar = '\"Things You Should Know\"';
        document.write(myVar.replace(/\\\"/g, '|'));
    </script>
<body>
<br>hello
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you have in your string are simple quotes, so simply use `/"/g`

Comment: /"/g -- as suggested by Denys Seguret -- is sufficient as goes regular expression syntax. The regular expression in javascript is a tool for searching inside a string. This example looks for a " within the variable's value. The answers below use /\"/g which also works in javascript. It also looks for a ". That backslash is unnecessary in vanilla regular expression syntax. In javascript, both ways work, however. Anyway, to search for a backslash followed by quote, you can use /\\"/g since you must use a backslashed backslash if you want the regular expression to look for a backslash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var myVar = '\"Things You Should Know\"';
document.write(myVar.replace(/\"/g, '|'));
```

The `\` escapes the next character so your string only reads `"Things You Should Know"`

Answer (score 4):

Your string doesn't have the sequence *backslash double-quote* in it. The backslash is an escape character so `\"` means `"` (this is useful in strings that are delimited by double quote characters).

If you did have that sequence in your string (by escaping the backslash characters):

```
var myVar = '\\"Things You Should Know\\"';
```

… then you could do it with:

```
var modifiedString = myVar.replace(/\\"/g, "|");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myVar.replace(/\\"/g, '|');
```

Also, that string you provided didn't have a backslash then a double-quote, it just had a double quote. You escaped the double-quote for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xRfKP/)

```
var myVar = '\"Things You Should Know\"';
var myVar1 = myVar.replace(/\"/g, '|');
alert(myVar1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable *has no backslashes*. `\"` in a string puts a quote character in the string. Example:

```
alert('\"Things You Should Know\"');
```

brings up a window that says

```
"Things You Should Know"
```